# Custom Validation Rule WPF and Items control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Within an `ItemsControl` which is bound to a data source, I am trying to validate a `TextBox` using a custom validation rule, which accepts a parameter, following is the code for the vaildation rule.

```
public class RatioValidation : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Maturity.MaturityValue) && Helper.IsDateInCorrectFormat(Maturity.MaturityValue))
        {
            String strVal = Convert.ToString(value);
            Double ratio = 0;
            Boolean isValid = Double.TryParse(strVal, out ratio);
            if (isValid)
            {
                if (ratio <= 0)
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid ratio!");
                else return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            }
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid ratio!");
        }
        else return new ValidationResult(true, null);           
    }

    private MaturityDependencyForValidation _maturity;
    public MaturityDependencyForValidation Maturity
    {
        get { return _maturity; }
        set { _maturity = value; }
    }
}

public class MaturityDependencyForValidation : DependencyObject
{
    public String MaturityValue
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(MaturityValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaturityValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaturityValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaturityValue", typeof(String), typeof(MaturityDependencyForValidation), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

And then use it like following,

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Name="txtRatio" BorderThickness="0" Width="148" Tag="{Binding StrMaturity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Ratio" Mode="TwoWay"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <leg:RatioValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                    <leg:RatioValidation.Maturity>
                         <leg:MaturityDependencyForValidation MaturityValue="{Binding txtMaturity}"/>
                    </leg:RatioValidation.Maturity>
                </leg:RatioValidation>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I get an exception in the output window:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=txtMaturity; DataItem=null; target element is 'MaturityDependencyForValidation' (HashCode=63478077); target property is 'Maturity' (type 'String')

And within the `RatioValidation` rule, the value of `Maturity` never gets bound from the data binding. I need this value for data binding. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `DataContext` as the surrounding objects, the binding at the very least, are not `DependencyObjects`, you are somewhat limited in your choices, it should be similar to what happens when [binding in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245116/bind-to-datacontext-property-inside-inline-array-delcaration/), also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886354/546730).

Comment: What's the work around? I want to validated individual (UserControl) items in the ItemsControl which is bound to a collection. The usercontrol generates one row for each item in the collection. Its something like a datagrid scenario where we can specify the rowvalidation property and validate individual row items. ANy suggestions please?

Comment: @VinayDwivedi: How about looking at the linked question?

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem... Looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886309/templatebinding-not-working-on-validationrules-dependency-property... And also it looks like your article... but providing the link would have helped... thanks so much anyways.

Comment: @VinayDwivedi: Both answers on both questions i linked to use the same techniques and one of the links has been there from the very start, you just didn't care to follow it...